# substring in conjunctions with datatable query

Tags: c#, linq, datatable

the query below is a query that will get data from a column to see if the data contains a certain string. this is string is found in that column i would like to select all of the data within them rows. for example in the the data-table the will be a row with "age[10-20]" and based on this input string it should output all of the row the string is "age"

the code below does not return any data there are nor errors

Is it possible to retrieve data based on a index value.

```
  var result = importedExcelData.AsEnumerable().Where(data => data.Field<String>("All Respondents").Contains(first))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing `.Where(data => data.Field<String>(first) == first)` to:

```
.Where(data => data.Field<String>(first).Contains(first)
```

Comment: A Tip: make sure to compare with a call of `ToLower()` on both side

Comment: i used the above and it returns nothing

Comment: Can you show us some sample data and what you expect to get back?

Comment: what i expect to get back is a return of all data that has that in a row and the other coloumns assicated with it.

Comment: i cant show it without asking clients and they wont be arounmd till wedneday the erqailest

Comment: What is the value of the `first` variable? Some sample data would really help =]

Comment: Can you make some up, stick some dummy values in there? I don't need to know names or anything, just anything to help me understand exactly what you're querying on =]

Comment: jus a quick question is is possible to query a datatable on a index an not the actual column name.

Comment: Not in a Linq query but if you have the data in a DataTable or something similar you should be able to access columns by index.